# Read from character vector CSV to tibble in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

TL;DR I’m wondering if readr or tibble or anything base/tidyverse can make a tibble from a character vector of CSV rows (as if I had done read_lines() on some CSV file).

More explanation:
I am collecting output (from stdout of a processx object) into a character vector, and this output is actually lines of a CSV, being created by the subprocess. I would like to make this into a tibble, but the only function I can find that does this is data.table::fread (via the ‘text’ arg). This is in a package and I don’t really want to take a dependency on data.table solely for this one function.

I’ve looked through the tidyverse docs and I can’t find anything. I realize I could write my own parser, and I started doing it with map_def and str_split but then I realized there are subtleties like “ignore the comma if it’s within quotes”, etc. maybe I’m just being lazy, but I don’t really want to implement a full csv parser when there are millions that already exist. Not to mention, speed concerns. This vector is sometimes 10k+ rows and I’m sure my homemade approach would not be the most optimized.

Any thoughts are welcome. Maybe I should just bite the bullet and either write the parser or use data.table but I feel like I can’t be the first person to want to do this and there must be something g built in that I’m missing. Thanks!

Comment: But did you *try* it? `readr::read_csv("a,b\n1,2")` works, as does `readr::read_csv(c("a,b","1,2"))`. In addition to sindri_baldur's point about `read.csv`, `data.table::fread` and `vroom::vroom` (though the latter does not accept a vector of strings, just a single `\n`-delimited string).

Comment: well, that was easy. I _thought_ I tried that, but I must've done something wrong. To be clear though, while `read.csv()` does work, as @sindri_baldur shows below, `readr::read_csv(c("a,b","1,2"))` does _not_ work and returns `Error: 'a,b' does not exist in current working directory`, which is what I saw originally. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. That `read_csv` invocation works for me without error; I'm on `readr-1.3.1`, perhaps `readr-2` changed that behavior? .... Yes, it did; see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/news/news.html, scroll down to version 2.0.0 under the **"Literal data"** header, and see that it now interprets vectors (len > 1) differently. You must be on `readr-2.*`.

Comment: ah great catch! My mistake for not posting the package versions I was using. Indeed `readr::read_csv(I(c("a,b","1,2")))` _does_ work in `readr >= 2.0.0`. Thanks.

Comment: Package versions are not *always* perfectly related, though admittedly it's the assumption of consistency between versions that can lead to problems in code or misunderstandings between the asker and us commenters/answerers. For instance, my first comment is true given the assumption that you and I are using the same version of `readr` ... which we are not :-)

Comment: Fair point. And also, I’m pretty sure readr 2.0.0 just came out in the past month, so somehow I find myself on the cutting edge of breaking changes! Luckily, wrapping the vector in I() works both pre- and post-2.0.0 readr. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `read.csv` not work?

```
read.csv(
  text = "a,b
          1,2",
  header = TRUE
)

#   a b
# 1 1 2
```

Comment: This works, although the OP was about a vector, but `read.csv(text = c("a,b","1,2"), header = TRUE)` works too (though as noted above, it does _not_ work with `readr::read_csv()`. Thanks!

Comment: @seth127 I figured you would be able to paste/split the vectors as needed before you feed them to read.csv().

Comment: yes, although I was hoping not to, for speed reasons. This data can be a bit large, as noted. Thank you though, this works great.